# como puedo visualizar las imagenes almacenadas en mi web api

Tags: html, .net-6.0

tengo una pequeña web api realizado en C# con Net6

la cuestion es que mis imagenes estan quedando almacenadas en una carpeta dentro de mi proyecto de web api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no se como poder visualizar esa imagen en mi proyecto localhost web, he consultado que tengo que agregar una propiedad al program.cs, que ya lo hice

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

mi etiqueta img tengo esto

```
<img src="https://localhost:7265/wwwroot/theme_ntp_background.jpeg">
```

pero no funciona, no se si lo estoy haciendo mal o me falta mucha cosa

gracias

Answer (score 0):

era el src

yo estaba colocando el `wwwroot`, tiene que ser directo sin el nombre del directorio